# Problems with sequelize one-to-many associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an existing database that I need to work with.

The user table looks like a bit like this:

```
id
name
storeId
```

The store table looks a bit like this:

```
id
name
address
```

The user can be associated to just one store. What I want to be able to do is this:

```
User.hasOne(models.Store, { foreignKey: 'storeId' } ); // Working with existing db, so I need to specify the column name
```

And then, be able to do something like this:

```
User.find(1, { include: [models.Store] })
```

However, just doing this doesn't work. I get the following errors:

```
Unknown column 'Store.storeId' in 'field list'
```

It is trying to run this query when I get that error:

```
SELECT `user`.*, `store`.`id` AS `store.id`, `store`.`name` AS `store.name`, `store`.`storeId` AS `store.storeId` FROM `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN `store` AS `store` ON `user`.`id` = `store`.`storeId` WHERE `user`.`id`=1 LIMIT 1;
```

Which is obviously wrong. It should be joining on `user.storeId = store.id`, and it should not being trying to select `store.storeId`.

I can't figure out how to make this work - any hints?

I am using sequelize v1.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User.hasOne(models.Store, { foreignKey: 'storeId' , as:'store'})

User.find(1, { include: [{model: models.Store, as: 'store'}] })
```

Comment: No - that has the same problem, actually. The eager loading doesn't work at all - meaning `store` is mysteriously missing completely from the the `user` object. If I run `user.getStore()` it will try this query: `SELECT * FROM store WHERE storeId = 2 LIMIT 1;`, which is using the user's id (2) instead of the store's id (17), and it is still using `storeId` instead of `id` in the query.